# Conditional formatting on textbox based on values in Tablix, its considering only first row of Tabix

Tags: reporting-services

I have multiple Tablix with multiple datasets.I have created a tabbed report with textboxes(like A,B,C) placed in Header row linking them to different Tablix(1,2,3) through bookmarks. I have used IIF condition for background color of Textbox A based on two column values in Tablix 1. But the textbox is highlighted only when first row of the Tablix is falls into the expression criteria and considering the remaining rows data.

```
=IIf(First(Fields!BP_Value.Value, "dtsConfiguration") <>First(Fields!AP_Value.Value, "dtsConfiguration"), "Red", "#b5adad")
```

I would like to highlight a text box when Fields!BP_Value.Value is not equal to Fields!AP_Value.Value

So which expression should I use in order to consider all the rows on Tablix instead of first row. Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Report Item instead of referencing the fields directly?

You will have your BP_Value and AP_Value in different boxes.. these text boxes either have names or called textbox1.. textbox 2 etc..

For clarity, I will call then  bp_textbox  and ap_textbox

What you can do is to set the background color expression to this instead:

```
=iif (Reportitems!bp_textbox.value <> Reportitems!ap_textbox.value, "Red", "#b5adad")
```

Comment: I have not tried it the way you mentioned but instead I added a calculated field column. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the FIRST from the statement:

```
=IIF(Fields!BP_Value.Value <>Fields!AP_Value.Value, "Red", "#b5adad")
```

Comment: I tried doing that but its not working. Its throwing me the following error: "The Background Expression for the textbox refers directly to field BP_Value  without specifying a dataset aggregate. When report contains multiple datasets, field references outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope."